# UV Unwrap face issue

Tags: texturing, uv

first time trying unwrapping/texturing and I am having issue with a fairly simple model.
Here is the model in question:
[image]

When it unwraps this face and all the similar faces along the inside come out so squashed that they are almost just an edge:
[image]

It makes it difficult to work with when drawing my texture after exporting the UV wrap, am I using seams wrong? Is there anything I can do here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

uv unwrapping is like cutting a box and flattening it out, like a paper.
So if there is a corner or a part that was not cut right it will be crushed or have a weird shape

There are a few ways to unwrap this model

## The quick and dirty method

1. First select everything and "clear seam" (open the "uv" menu from the top left side of the window> and click on "clear seam")
2. Select only around the exterior of the binding all around the book and "mark seem" [image: ![see photo]
3. Select only around the inside of the book were the pages are and "mark seem"
4. Select all and click unwrap and voilà you unwrapped your book
5. Now you can play with the uv map and fit it with your image
   [image: ![and fit it with your image]

## The professional way

1. First select everything and "clear seam" (open the "uv" menu from the top left side of the window> and click on "clear seam")
2. Fix your mesh with diagonal lines so there won't be any polygons with only 3 edges [image: Fix your mesh image 1]  [image: Fix your mesh image 2]
3. Select only around the inside of the book were the pages are and "mark seem"
4. Select and mark only the seams of the binder, see images
   [image: mark only the seams of the binder image]
   [image: mark only the seams of the binder image 2]
5. unwrap and fit to size

[image: final product]